# Amorphous Process using Savant Core Demonic Forms

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

The Savant Core Technology (FoH p.125) states that the skill must be chosen when this Technology is chosen.  What if you use Amorphous? (FoH p.127)  Can it change each time since it's added ad-hoc?  What if you choose it later as a permanent part of your demonic form?  Can you chose a different skill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Amorphous* Process allows you to switch out one Technology for another.  The *Savant Core* Technology gives you access to a skill at the five-dot level.  The question is whether or not you view swapping *Savant Core* in a different skill is swapping a Technology to a different Technology.

If the StoryTeller would permit a player character to choose *Savant Core* twice for two different skills, there's no reason not to allow a player to switch skills as a change of Technology.

This isn't overpowered because the player is expending their choice of Process on this ability, and Processes are very powerful Form abilities. A Process should be very powerful.  In addition, switching skills would take Aether, and (oddly) if the player switches from skill A to skill B, to switch to skill C they have to return to skill A first, expending more Aether.

Comment: Taking what you said above, if I took Amorphous and switched out two Technologies, then I could have 2 skills at 5 dots and then reset them when I go back to Cover.  The next time, I could choose two different skills if I swapped them out.   What if I had Savant Core already?  If I "swap it out" for another Savant Core, then I can get a different skill at 5 dots?  I can see this being something like 4 different skills at 5 dots if you have both Technologies as Savant Core and "swap" them for two others.

Comment: Once you have the *Amorphous* Process you can, in principle, have access to an infinite number of five dot skills, but only one at a time.   You might even have more than one five dot skill at a time, but at the cost of losing one of your Technologies.  This is the ability you have gained by choosing *Amorphous*, instead of some other (comparably beneficial) Process.